# Moving Stored Procedures from SSMS into TFS 2012

Tags: sql-server, tfs, sql-server-2012

I am needing to move all of my stored procedures into TFS 2012. I was wondering what the best/fastest way to accomplish this is. I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: You could generate a single script of all your stored procedures (e.g. by using the [wizard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895179.aspx) ) and then check that into source control. Or, depending on your Visual Studio version, you could do something like create a database project, [reverse engineer](http://candordeveloper.com/2013/01/08/creating-a-sql-server-database-project-in-visual-studio-2012/) from the existing SQL Server 2012 database and then check the DB project into source control

Comment: I agree that a database project is definetely the way to go

Comment: Is this a one-off task, or do you intend to do this regularly?

Answer (score 3):

Our suggestion would be to use the SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) and create a database schema change management project in Visual Studio that you can then check-in to Team Foundation Server.  It has quite a few benefits like being able to "compile" the schema and has tools that can be used in generating automatic change scripts for target servers (whether they are empty, test, or even production servers).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx

Comment: +1, this is what we do - sans the crappy autoamtic change scripts that are pure delta and do not take data transformation into account. But this is a great way to start versioning a database schema.

Answer (score 1):

SSDT is definitely the way to go, It's a component of Visual Studio. There is an SSDT for database projects, and SSDT-BI for reports etc.

Create a database project in Visual Studio and add your database objects (stored procedures, views, functions, tables, schemas etc) into the project. It allows for all database objects to be stored in there (even database roles/users, certificates, keys etc).

Alternatively, you can use Visual Studio to import a database from a server. It will read your database and populate the project with all the objects from that database. It's very cool.

You can check in to TFS as you would with any other project which allows you to do versioning (with comments), attach that work to TFS tickets (if you manage your workload that way) and perform branching and merging and you can also compare different versions of the project or the project against already deployed versions.

Once you're happy with your database you can 'publish' your project up to a server of your choosing. This is a very useful method for creating code that can be deployed to multiple environments (i.e. different dev/test environments). You can also compare your project against a deployed version to see changes. For example, you could compare your project against a test environment to see what the differences are and generate a script to update the test environment to match source (or vice-versa).

SSDT is great for deployments because it calculates how to apply your database project (rather than just dropping the database and creating a new one). You can also use pre & post deployment scripts to work with data or add permissions onto your objects for example.

You can publish to a database/server, script or DACPAC (which is the format for copying your entire project/database schema and allows you to perform deployments/drift reports etc from outside of Visual Studio)